# jpg not picked during pdf generation in dev environment java

Tags: java

> com.openhtmltopdf.exception WARNING:: IO problem for https://180.151.248.194:20505/resources/logo.jpg

path=request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()+ request.getContextPath() + "/resources/logo.jpg";

the way in which i fetch logo

i am getting this issue during pdf generation it works fine in my local system but not in  dev environment

Comment: please let me know any suggestions becuase in devlopment environment it works fine but in production it not picked

Answer (score 0):

We need more informations to see the problem here.
But you might want to make sure that you can access the image link from your prod server machine "https://180.151.248.194:20505/resources/logo.jpg".

If not, you might want to check your path (try a static path first instead of calling methods to generate it)

I'm not sure about this, but you might want to check the R/W privileges of your image and that it is not used by another process (just to see what causes the problem).

But if you said that it worked on your local, it is probably just a path problem or some security protocol.

Comment: in my local path is http and in dev its https  but still image is available there  but it not picking this it shows the error that    com.openhtmltopdf.exception WARNING:: IO problem

Comment: What version of JDK are you using ?

Comment: iam using jdk1.8

Comment: What kind of encryption are you using for https ? is it letsencrypt ? it is probably a security compatibility related problem.
Can you send me the full log of your exception ? 
You might also want to send me the line of your code where you get that exception.

Comment: thanks but now i am using relative path an its working thanks a lot